# How to add Header and Subheader in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

Could Anyone explain How to add Header and Subheader in Gridview shown in the below picture!![image]

Comment: Not clear , please get new image then put here .

Comment: Rather than the image, please add your code (for future reference).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

hi you can do it like this

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="grvMergeHeader" runat="server" 
                      BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
                      BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="5px" 
                      CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" 
                      GridLines="None" BorderStyle="None" CellSpacing="2" 
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                      OnRowCreated="grvMergeHeader_RowCreated">
              <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
              <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" 
                      HorizontalAlign="Center" />
              <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
              <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartMentID" 
                                HeaderText="DepartMentID" 
                                SortExpression="DepartMentID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartMent" 
                                HeaderText="DepartMent" 
                                SortExpression="DepartMent" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" 
                                HeaderText="Name" 
                                SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" 
                                HeaderText="Location" 
                                SortExpression="Location" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [DepartMentID], [DepartMent], [Name], [Location] FROM [Employee]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        &nbsp;</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
protected void grvMergeHeader_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "Department";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            HeaderCell = new TableCell();
            HeaderCell.Text = "Employee";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);

            grvMergeHeader.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

        }
```

Comment: How can I do the same for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556878/how-to-insert-a-table-row-of-dropdownlist-inside-the-header-as-a-second-in-a-gri

Comment: I tried the same but I am also calling a function on PAGE LOAD which references one of the table cell but it can't access it and gives me the `The name '' does not exist in current content`.

Comment: It is important to say that if you want your cells to be rendered as `<th>` reather than `<td>` you should use a `TableHeaderCell` instead of `TableCell`

Comment: @Ramesh  
A query
I have performed as the answer and I left everything ok but now when I try to grab a cell I get as error example:

Grvexample.headerrow.cells [1]. Attribute ["hidenn"].

I get an error and states that it has to have the same hut and footer as I can solve this problem

Comment: @RameshRajendran When I add according to the answer that resolves to appear header in gridview if I get it correctly but the error esque when I put this code: I get error

 GrvPagosAcum.DataBind ();
                GrvPagosAcum.HeaderRow.Cells [3] .Attributes ["data-hide"] = "phone";
                GrvPagosAcum.HeaderRow.Cells [4] .Attributes ["data-hide"] = "phone";

Comment: @Pierro  still am not seeing any error in your comments.

Comment: @RameshRajendran 
If when I put that code I get an error that indicates that the header must be the same as the foot

Comment: How would you handle this if you decided to use column template fields instead of using `<asp:boundField>`

Comment: The HeaderGrid variable is unused, the row containing its declaration shoud be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the nice post check once

http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1077/gridview-multiple-header-rows

[Require Two Header Row in Grid View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102861/require-two-header-row-in-grid-view)

http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2010/12/how-to-create-multiple-row-header-and.html