# how to add header and sub header to grid in runtime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, grid, janus

I am a janous grid and i setup that in runtime , i need add header and sub header to grid.
and header contains two part ,that some field in one part and some field in other part.
could any one to explain how to do it.

[image]

I use C# windows form application;

```
        Col = new UltraGridColumn();
        Col.Caption = "Row";
        Col.Width = 10;
        Col.HeaderAlignment = Janus.Windows.GridEX.TextAlignment.Center;
        Col.Key = "Row";
        Col.DataMember = "Row";
        MyGrid.Columns.Add(Col);

        Col = new UltraGridColumn();
        Col.Caption = "Name";
        Col.HeaderAlignment = Janus.Windows.GridEX.TextAlignment.Center;
        Col.Key = "Name";
        Col.DataMember = "Name";
        MyGrid.Columns.Add(Col);

        Col = new UltraGridColumn();
        Col.Caption = "Family";
        Col.HeaderAlignment = Janus.Windows.GridEX.TextAlignment.Center;
        Col.Key = "Family";
        Col.DataMember = "Family";
        MyGrid.Columns.Add(Col);

        Col = new UltraGridColumn();
        Col.Caption = "Address";
        Col.Key = "Address";
        Col.Width = MyGrid.Width * 18 / 100;
        Col.DataMember = "Address";
        Col.HeaderAlignment = Janus.Windows.GridEX.TextAlignment.Center;
        MyGrid.Columns.Add(Col);

        Col = new UltraGridColumn();
        Col.Caption = "Tel";
        Col.Key = "Tel";
        Col.Width = 0;
        Col.DataMember = "Tel";
        Col.HeaderAlignment = Janus.Windows.GridEX.TextAlignment.Center;
        MyGrid.Columns.Add(Col);
```

Comment: Did you see this link?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327749/how-to-add-header-and-subheader-in-gridview

Comment: yes, i have a same problem but with janous grid in win form app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridEXColumnSet` class to group columns the way you want.

This is code snippet:

```
Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXColumnSet CS = new Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXColumnSet();
CS.Caption = "Department";
CS.HeaderAlignment = Janus.Windows.GridEX.TextAlignment.Center;
CS.ColumnCount = 2;
CS.Width = 200;
CS.Key = "Department";
MyGrid.RootTable.ColumnSets.Add(CS);
```

Then you can add your columns this way:

```
CS.Add(col1, 0, 0); // First parameter is GridEXColumn, Second is row in ColumnSet, third is col
CS.Add(col2, 0, 2);
```

Comment: hi adel , thanks for response ,
in line CS.Add(col1 ,0 ,0) , i get error 
error : Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Comment: in form load call SetupGrid method.