# Remove empty row append by Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridBranchTiming" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0"
                    AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15" Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="gridBranchTiming_PageIndexChanging"
                    CssClass="mGrid" OnRowDeleting="gridBranchTiming_RowDeleting"
                    OnRowCommand="gridBranchTiming_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="gridBranchTiming_RowCreated" >

                    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <th rowspan="2">#</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Branch ID</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">From</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">To</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Sunday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Monday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Tuesday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Wednesday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Thursday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Friday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Saturday </th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Edit</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Delete</th>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>

                                </tr>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <td><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("BranchID") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("fromDate") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("toDate") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("SundayIn") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("SundayOut") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("MondayIn") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("MondayOut") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("TuesdayIn") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("TuesdayOut") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("WednesdayIn") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("WednesdayOut") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("ThursdayIn") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("ThursdayOut") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("FridayIn") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("FridayOut") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("SaturdayIn") %></td>
                                <td><%#Eval("SaturdayOut") %></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="aEdit" title="Edit" href='EditBranchTiming.aspx?Id=<%#Eval("BranchTimeEntryID") %>'>Edit</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CssClass="aDelete" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" OnClientClick=' javascript:return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"); '
                                        CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BranchTimeEntryID") %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>

                                </td>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

But when it renders in browser there is an extra empty column appended to my grid. I cant figure out how that empty row get append.

This is how the output look like

[image: Screenshot]

and the browser code when inspecting is this

```
<table class="mGrid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridBranchTiming" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th scope="col">
                                </th><th rowspan="2">#</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Branch ID</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">From</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">To</th>
                                <th colspan="2">Sunday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Monday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Tuesday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Wednesday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Thursday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Friday </th>
                                <th colspan="2">Saturday </th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Edit</th>
                                <th rowspan="2">Delete</th>
                                </tr><tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>
                                    <th>From</th>
                                    <th>To</th>

                                </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                                </td><td>1</td>
                                <td>NBAD004</td>
                                <td>18/02/2015</td>
                                <td>24/02/2015</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="aEdit" title="Edit" href="EditBranchTiming.aspx?Id=6">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick=" javascript:return confirm(&quot;Are you sure you want to delete?&quot;); ;" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridBranchTiming_lnkDelete_0" title="Delete" class="aDelete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridBranchTiming$ctl02$lnkDelete','')">Delete</a>

                                </td>

        </tr><tr class="alt">
            <td>
                                </td><td>2</td>
                                <td>NBAD004</td>
                                <td>01/01/2014</td>
                                <td>31/12/2014</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>11:00</td>
                                <td>14:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>00:00</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="aEdit" title="Edit" href="EditBranchTiming.aspx?Id=1019">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick=" javascript:return confirm(&quot;Are you sure you want to delete?&quot;); ;" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gridBranchTiming_lnkDelete_1" title="Delete" class="aDelete" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gridBranchTiming$ctl03$lnkDelete','')">Delete</a>

                                </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Any idea to get rid of that empty column????

Comment: try alluserstoaddrows property to false.

Comment: this is not the way you should use a `GridView`. Each template creates a `th`(HeaderTemplate) and `td`(ItemTemplate). In all possibilities, the current design outputs an invalid markup which the browser autocorrects. You should rather be using an `asp:ListView`. Are you using jQuery in your project?

Comment: Yes I use jQuery in my project

Answer (score 0):

This is a *very ugly hack* which will solve your issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table.mGrid th:first-child").remove();
    $("table.mGrid td:first-child").remove();
});
```

But you must really be using a ListView like this.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="job_id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <th rowspan="2">#</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Branch ID</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">From</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">To</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Sunday </th>
                    <th colspan="2">Monday </th>
                    <th colspan="2">Tuesday </th>
                    <th colspan="2">Wednesday </th>
                    <th colspan="2">Thursday </th>
                    <th colspan="2">Friday </th>
                    <th colspan="2">Saturday </th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Edit</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">Delete</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("BranchID") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("fromDate") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("toDate") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("SundayIn") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("SundayOut") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("MondayIn") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("MondayOut") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("TuesdayIn") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("TuesdayOut") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("WednesdayIn") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("WednesdayOut") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("ThursdayIn") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("ThursdayOut") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("FridayIn") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("FridayOut") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("SaturdayIn") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("SaturdayOut") %></td>
            <td>
                <a class="aEdit" title="Edit" 
                    href='EditBranchTiming.aspx?Id=<%#Eval("BranchTimeEntryID") %>'>Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" 
                CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BranchTimeEntryID") %>'
                CommandName="delete"
                CssClass="aDelete" 
                ToolTip="Delete"  
                OnClientClick=' javascript:return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"); '>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

ASP.NET framework has introduced `asp:ListView` to give more flexibility over the generated markup. Another method is using `GridView`s `RowCreated` event like this.
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18327885/17447