# How to assign gridview header text

Tags: asp.net, gridview, c#-3.0

I am developing a automated result sheet for my college and I have also attached a screen shot of the result sheet. I have almost able to develop 95% of the result sheet using gridview, now my only problem is I don't know how to assign a second header to each column. As you can see in the image there are 5 subject (P11MCA51,..,P11MCA55) and each subject has 6 fields(C,S,T,CR,GP,GR). From the below code I have developed till the subject code but I am stuck as I don't know how to insert those 6 fields.

```
<pre>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="3px" 
            Width="550px" Visible="True">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="USN" HeaderText="Usn" SortExpression="USN"  ReadOnly = "true"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name"  ReadOnly = "true"/>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P11MCA41" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="C" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="S" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="T" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="CR" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="GP" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="GR" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="P11MCA42" ItemStyle-Width="200px"> 
                 <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="C" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="S" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="T" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="CR" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="GP" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 <asp:TextBox ID="GR" runat="server" Width = "30px" ReadOnly = "true" Text='<%# Eval("T1") %>' />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>



            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle BorderColor="#660033" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#CCFFCC" BorderColor="#6600FF" BorderStyle="Double" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </pre>
```

Link of the image : "https://plus.google.com/photos/105587850868503389652/albums/6127575275561544033/6127575300226827650?pid=6127575300226827650&oid=105587850868503389652&authkey=CNeHoLjSzMmAigE"

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1077/gridview-multiple-header-rows). and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327749/how-to-add-header-and-subheader-in-gridview).

Comment: Can you please let me know how to specify range of column in ColumnSpan. I am having 8 columned GridView and I would like to add a header text for only last six. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following links.
[Thirumalai's article on Dot Net Twitter](http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2010/12/how-to-create-multiple-row-header-and.html)

or [Ali Adravis's solution](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1077/gridview-multiple-header-rows)

Comment: Kami, I followed your links and I could only able to do till here : <pre>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" CssClass = "gvAltRow td"
Width="609px">
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
 
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Usn" ReadOnly = "true"/>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly = "true"/>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
<th colspan = "4" rowspan = "1"> Caption </th>
<tr>
<th> 1st </th>
<th> 2nd </th>
<th> 3rd </th>
<th> 4th </th>
<th> 5th </th>
<th> 6th </th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
</pre>

Comment: I want the 1st and 2nd (Header Text) to start from 3 column and also the thin line after the 3rd column which extends till the Top Header(Caption) text to be removed. Please help me with this tiny problem. Thank you