# How to achieve multiple colspan and multiple header row using ASP.Net gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, html-table

I'm in a situation were need to achieve multiple colspan and two header row using ASP.Net gridview.

Something like below

```
+----------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|Name      |English                         |Math                            |
|          |----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|          |1st Term  |2nd Term  |3rd Term  |1st Term  |2nd Term  |3rd Term  |    
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Adam      |50        |60        |70        |55        |65        |75        |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|Smith     |52        |62        |72        |57        |68        |70        |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Is it possible to do it?

Edit : Number of rows and / or columns or even sub-headers of a header is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but it takes a bit of trial and error to get the design you want. Use the GridView `OnRowDataBound` event. It would be easier to do this after the GridView is build, especially for `RowSpan`.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        int spanColumn_1_start = 1;
        int spanColumn_1_length = 3;

        //apply colspan
        e.Row.Cells[spanColumn_1_start].ColumnSpan = 3;

        //remove the spanned cells
        for (int i = 1; i < spanColumn_1_length; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(spanColumn_1_start + 1);
        }

        //note that the startindex of the 2nd colspan is set after removing cells for 1st colspan
        int spanColumn_2_start = 2;
        int spanColumn_2_length = 3;

        //apply colspan
        e.Row.Cells[spanColumn_2_start].ColumnSpan = 3;

        //remove the spanned cells
        for (int i = 1; i < spanColumn_2_length; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(spanColumn_2_start + 1);
        }
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int rowIndex = e.Row.DataItemIndex;

        //to make a rowspan you have to work backwards since the next row does not exist yet
        if (rowIndex == 1)
        {
            GridView1.Rows[rowIndex - 1].Cells[0].RowSpan = 2;
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        //span 4 rows in column 3 starting at row 6
        if (rowIndex == 9)
        {
                int rowSpan = 4;
                int columnIndex = 3;

                //apply rowspan
                GridView1.Rows[rowIndex - rowSpan].Cells[columnIndex].RowSpan = rowSpan;

                //remove the spanned rows
                for (int i = 1; i < rowSpan; i++)
                {
                    GridView1.Rows[rowIndex - (rowSpan - i)].Cells.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The above snippet will give the following result.

[image: result]

**UPDATE**

To add an extra header row you need to use the `OnRowCreated` event of the GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a gridview
    GridView gv = sender as GridView;

    //check if the row is the header row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //create a new row
        GridViewRow extraHeader = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
        extraHeader.BackColor = Color.Green;

        //loop all the columns and create a new cell for each
        for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "ExtraHeader " + i;

            //add the cell to the new header row
            extraHeader.Cells.Add(cell);
        }

        //add the new row to the gridview
        gv.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, extraHeader);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this was not what I asked. I want to achieve multiple header row. But what you done is created a single header row with multiple colspan. Yeah, I was needed this. But additionally I need one more header row which contains header for each column.

Comment: You now know how you can do that with my snippet, just tweak it a little.

Comment: @VDWWD It's not apparent at all from your snippet how to add an additional header row

Comment: Added the snippet to create an extra header row.

Answer (score 2):

Access to the `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` for a grid view is done through the `Cells` property.

To access the header cells:

```
//Replace ColumnSpan with RowSpan if needed (and if you can get multiple header rows)
Gridview1.HeaderRow.Cells[CELL_INDEX].ColumnSpan = 2; //Need to know the cell index
```

To access the cells of a normal row:

```
//Replace ColumnSpan with RowSpan if needed
Gridview1.Rows[ROW_INDEX].Cells[CELL_INDEX].ColumnSpan = 2; //Need to know the row index and the cell index in that row
```

The multiple header row might be a bit more tricky. I've never done it, but the guy here seemed to have a good answer: [How to add Header and Subheader in Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327749/how-to-add-header-and-subheader-in-gridview)

Comment: I've also seen the answer. But my problem is I'm getting all of my columns at runtime. Thus I don't know the name of the columns of even how much columns exist.

Comment: @ParvezMRobin I found this one for dynamic headers. Hopefully this can help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27824/Dynamic-Multiple-Row-Column-Grid-Header