# ASP.NET Gridview within Gridview but without the header for each row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I tried using the gridview within gridview in asp.net and this is what I've done

[image]

the problem with that is the header become annoying if the rows are too many. I wanted the inner gridview to share common headers like this:

[image]

is this possible in ASP.NET? How?

sample gridview markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="ItemsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" CssClass="gridviews" Width="600px"
BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="5" OnRowCommand="ItemsGridView_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="DepartmentId">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton CommandName="GoDet" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="#676771" Font-Bold="True" ID="linkDepartmentId" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DepartmentId") %>'
                Text="View" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="300px" Wrap="False"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub-Groups">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="SubGroupGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" CssClass="subgridviews"
                DataSource='<%# Bind("SubGroupees") %>' BorderStyle="Outset" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="3" ShowHeader="False" GridLines="Vertical"     OnRowCommand="SubGroupGridView_RowCommand">
                <Columns>


                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name">

                        <ItemStyle Width="180px" />
                    </asp:BoundField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="SubGroupId">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton CommandName="GoSubDet" ID="linkSubGroupId" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="#676771" Font-Bold="True"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SubGroupId") %>' Text="Edit" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="SubGroupId">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton CommandName="DelSub" ID="linkDelSub" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="#676771" Font-Bold="True"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SubGroupId") %>'
                                Text="Delete" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="DepartmentId">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton CommandName="AddSub" ID="linkSubGroupId" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="#676771" Font-Bold="True" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DepartmentId") %>'
                Text="Add Sub-Group" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" SortExpression="DepartmentId">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton CommandName="DelItem" ID="linkDelDepartmentId" Font-Underline="false" ForeColor="#676771" Font-Bold="True" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DepartmentId") %>'
                Text="Delete" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>


</Columns>
```

Comment: Please show your gridview markup.

Comment: use ShowHeader="False". '<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeader="False">
        </asp:GridView>'

Comment: @Sandeep, that will make all of the headers disappear. I wanted to make the inner grid to have just one common header for every row

Comment: may this will help you out [How to add Header and Subheader in Gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327749/how-to-add-header-and-subheader-in-gridview)

Comment: if header is the only problem than you can also use gridview rowdatabound event and check  e.row.index. if index is 1 than showHeader="True" else "False"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnRowDataBound` event for that in the parent GridView and check if the nested GridView is the first one and only show the headers in the first.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //find the nested grid in the current row with findcontrol
        GridView gridView = e.Row.FindControl("nestedGridView") as GridView;

        //check if it is the first nested gridview and show/hide the header
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            gridView.ShowHeader = true;
        }
        else
        {
            gridView.ShowHeader = false;
        }

        //fill the nested grid with data
        gridView.DataSource = dataSource;
        gridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```