# Freeze Grid View Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am used two table first one for header and other one for body. From the JavaScript i am changing the header table each column width which same as body table. Each time on dropdownlist select index changes grid bind operation performs.Each time column width change for that I am use below JavaScript.

Here I am writing JavaScript Code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var headergrid = $('#gridHeader').find("table")[0];
  var bodygrid = $('#bodyHeader').find("table")[0];
  var headerCellWidths = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < bodygrid.getElementsByTagName('TH').length; i++) {
    headerCellWidths[i] = bodygrid.getElementsByTagName('TH')[i].offsetWidth;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < headerCellWidths.length; i++) {
    headergrid.getElementsByTagName('TH')[i].style.width = parseInt(headerCellWidths[i]) + 'px';
  }
});
```

ASP CODE :

```
<div style="height: 34px; overflow: auto" id="gridHeader">
  <table id="tbltemp" width="856px">
    <tr id="temp">
      <th>
        TRANS ID
      </th>
      <th>
        VC NO.
      </th>
      <th>
        SUB NO.
      </th>
      <th>
       DOMAIN
      </th>
      <th>
        STATION
      </th>
      <th>
        DTC
      </th>
      <th>
        STATUS
      </th>
      <th>
        REMARK
      </th>
      <th>
        ENTERED DATETIME
      </th>
      <th>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="width: 859px; height: 450px; overflow: auto;" id="bodyHeader">
  <asp:GridView ID="gvViewData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EC_TRANS_ID"
    OnRowDataBound="gvViewRow_DataBound" OnDataBound="gvViewData_DataBound" OnRowCommand="gvViewData_RowCommand"
    Visible="False" BackColor="White" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvViewData_SelectedIndexChanging"
  >
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="EC_TRANS_ID" HeaderText="TRANS ID" ReadOnly="True">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="VC_NO" HeaderText="VC NO" ReadOnly="True">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="SUB_NO" HeaderText="SUB NO">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="RESERVED" HeaderText="Part No">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="DOMAIN_NAME" HeaderText="DOMAIN">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="STATION_ID" HeaderText="STATION">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="DTC_CODE" HeaderText="DTC">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="STATUS" HeaderText="STATUS">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="REMARK" HeaderText="REMARK">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ENTERED_DATETIME" HeaderText="ENTERED DATETIME" >
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
      </asp:BoundField>
      <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Prameters" Text="Parameter">
        <ItemStyle />
      </asp:ButtonField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>        
</div>
```

But issue is that if width set as 110px it assigned as 105px or 68px then its assigned as 72px. Please give me some suggestion.

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327749/how-to-add-header-and-subheader-in-gridview is what you are trying to do. Please refer it.

Comment: Not sure what browser you're using but if you go into the browser debug tools (F12) and inspect the element.  It will tell you where the styling is coming from